# How do I distribute files in AWS Buckets?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, async-await, file-handling

I am working on a project where I am fetching list of files in either .xml or .zip extension from one folder location and I am trying store them on S3 bucket locations on AWS cloud. I am assigning the string variables from the DirectoryWatcher Class & invoking the method below:

```
public static async Task UploadFilestoS3Async(string archiveDir, string storeKey, string registerType, List<string> fileNames, string logDir)
    {

        foreach (var file in fileNames)
        {
            try
            {
                var fileKey = storeKey + "/" + registerType + "/" + file;
                string fullArchivePath = archiveDir + file;
                if (File.Exists(fullArchivePath))
                {
                    var req = new PutObjectRequest
                    {
                        
                        // Distributing .xml & .zip files in relevant buckets
                        BucketName = file.EndsWith(".xml") ? "xmlBucket" : "zipBucket",
                        Key = fileKey,
                        FilePath = fullArchivePath
                    };

                    await _s3Client.PutObjectAsync(req);
                    string message = $"Store Key: {storeKey}, register type: {registerType}, file: {file} uploaded to S3 at {DateTime.UtcNow}";
                    await _logger.Info(message);
                    //Upload to S3
                    await Service.AppendLogtoFile(logDir, storeKey, message, LogType.Info);
                }
                else
                {
                    await _logger.Error($"Store Key: {storeKey}, register type: {registerType}, file: {file} not found at {DateTime.UtcNow}");
                    //Upload to S3
                    await Service.AppendLogtoFile(logDir, storeKey, $"Store Key: {storeKey}, register type: {registerType}, file: {file} not found at {DateTime.UtcNow}", LogType.Error);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await _logger.Error($"UploadFilestoS3Async: General exception with Store Key: {storeKey}, register type: {registerType}");
                //Upload to S3
                await Service.AppendLogtoFile(logDir, storeKey, $"UploadFilestoS3Async: General exception with Store Key: {storeKey}, register type: {registerType}, error: {ex.Message} stack trace: {ex.StackTrace}", LogType.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue I am having is in xmlBucket not all of the xmlFiles are getting uploaded while all the zip files and additional xml files are uploading in zipBucket. I want "xmlBucket" to only have .xml files & "zipBucket" to only have .zip files. Am I implementing the async method in an incorrect way? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You are checking if the file ends with `.xml` and using the xml bucket but all other files use the zip bucket.  my only thought is that if the file extension is not exactly `.xml` (such as `.XML`) it will default to the zipbucket.  Are the xml files going to the zip bucket have a slightly different extension?  you may need to make that `EndsWith` check case insensitive or cover other extensions that may map more closely to XML

Comment: Yeah, I think so some of the files, did have .XML, so EndsWith does comparison of case sensitive by default correct?

Comment: yes, i'm not super familiar with C# but you can run a lowercase function on the filename before you do the ends with check to make it case insensitive